# How to make this?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a small game, and having some problems, that I hope you can help me with. I have 4 questions in this post.

1. How to update the JS function to html
2. How to save money, xp and level?
3. How to make a leveling system with a max level
4. How to make random number in the function

JS code:

```
var money = 0;
var xp = 0;
var level = 0;

function startClick(number){
    money = money + 50; //Want it to be random number to get
    xp = xp + 100; //Same here
}
```

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and not suitable for StackOverflow. You need to read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried? Programming a game might be a great way of learning JS, but you need to know the basics. You posted almost no code and expect others to write the rest for you? I'm sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is extremely but i'm bored

This is a good guide to make a simple idle game [Guide](http://dhmholley.co.uk/incrementals.html), you can take the knowledge you learn from the guide to make your own small game.

1. **How to update the JS to html**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b60jjg13/)

You are going to use `document.getElementById("thekey").innerHTML = thekey;`in the function

```
var money = 0;
var xp = 0;
var level = 0;

function startClick(number){
    money = parseInt(money) + 50; //Want it to be random number to get
    xp = xp + 100;//Same here
    //This will update money,xp to your html
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money; 
    document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
}
```

2. **How to save data**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b60jjg13/1/)

[Good guide about localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

To save your data ex. money, xp and levels, you are going to use localStorage.

```
var money = 0;
var xp = 0;
var level = 0;

//This loads the data
if(localStorage.money) money = localStorage.getItem('money');
//This updates the data when you load the html
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;

if(localStorage.xp) xp = localStorage.getItem('xp');
document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;

function startClick(number){
    money = parseInt(money) + 50; //Want it to be random number to get
    xp = parseInt(xp) + 100;//Same here
    //This will update money,xp to your html
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    //This sets the data, so "getItem" can load it
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
    document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
    localStorage.setItem('xp', xp);

}
```

3. **How to you make a leveling system with max level**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b60jjg13/2/)

To make a simple leveling system with max level, you are going to use if..else and 1 function.

```
var money = 0;
var xp = 0;
var level = 0;

//This loads the data
if(localStorage.money) money = localStorage.getItem('money');
//This updates the data when you load the html
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;

if(localStorage.xp) xp = localStorage.getItem('xp');
document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;

if(localStorage.level) level = localStorage.getItem('level');
document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;

//This will set the max level, you can change the max by change 30 to what you want.
if(level > 30){
    level = 30;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
}

//This is your leveling system, its combine to the button with startClick.
function levelClick(number){
if(xp >= 500){
    level = parseInt(level) + 1;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
    xp = parseInt(xp) - 500;
    document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
    localStorage.setItem('level', level);
    }
}

function startClick(number){
    money = parseInt(money) + 50; //Want it to be random number to get
    xp = parseInt(xp) + 100;//Same here
    //This will update money,xp to your html
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    //This sets the data, so "getItem" can load it
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
    document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
    localStorage.setItem('xp', xp);

}
```

4. **How to generate random numbers**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b60jjg13/3/)

To generate random numbers in startClick, you are going to use `Math.random`
  like `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - min + min)) + 1;` add it to your function and use the  `var random` like `money = parseInt(money) + random;` it will generate a random number everytime.

```
var money = 0;
var xp = 0;
var level = 0;

//This loads the data
if(localStorage.money) money = localStorage.getItem('money');
//This updates the data when you load the html
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;

if(localStorage.xp) xp = localStorage.getItem('xp');
document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;

if(localStorage.level) level = localStorage.getItem('level');
document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;

//This will set the max level, you can change the max by change 30 to what you want.
if(level > 30){
    level = 30;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
}

//This is your leveling system, its combine to the button with startClick.
function levelClick(number){
if(xp >= 500){
    level = parseInt(level) + 1;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
    xp = parseInt(xp) - 500;
    document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
    localStorage.setItem('level', level);
    }
}

function startClick(number){
    //This generate a random number, every time you click the button
    var moneyrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 100 + 100)) + 1;
    var xprandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 100 + 100)) + 1;
    money = parseInt(money) + moneyrandom; 
    xp = parseInt(xp) + xprandom;
    //This will update money,xp to your html
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    //This sets the data, so "getItem" can load it
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
    document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = xp;
    localStorage.setItem('xp', xp);

}
```

Comment: Just be aware that localStorage is not permanent.